# How to Exclude Fields from Navigation Property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am trying to learn .NET 5 with using ASP.NET Core 5. These days I am working on a blog project that developing with ASP.NET Core 5 MVC & NLayer architecture. This project uses Entity Framework Core 5.

Yesterday, I decided to develop only Admin Dashboard as MVC. For the frontend I will present the data as JSON output. However, I faced a problem about this topic. The JSON Output has a lot of unnecessary fields, and it can be dangerous if some fields are visible to the user. For example, `PasswordHash` field. The entity class has `navigation property` and it mapped in `DataAccess` layer. I want some fields not to appear in the JSON output. For example, the `Article` object has a `User` field. There is also an `Articles` field in this `User` field. I want to extract `PasswordHash` and `Articles` from `User` object. How can I do it?

The image with the JSON output below has too many fields that shouldn't be in the output, and too much repetitive data. For example, while developing with `Django Rest Framework`, we could use `exclude` to restrict the fields to be shown in the `serializer`. How can I do this in a `.Net 5` project? It is not visible in the image, but the category object at the bottom still contains the articles field.

[image: JSON Output]

Entity:

```
namespace Blog.Entities.Concrete
{
    public class Article : EntityBase, IEntity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int ViewsCount { get; set; } = 0;
        public int CommentCount { get; set; } = 0;
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        // fields for seo
        public string SeoAuthor { get; set; }
        public string SeoDescription { get; set; }
        public string SeoTags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Business Layer - Manager method:

```
public async Task<IDataResult<ArticleListDto>> GetAll()
{
    var articles = await _unitOfWork.Articles
                                    .GetAllAsync(null, a => a.User, a => a.Category);

    if (articles.Count > -1)
    {
        return new DataResult<ArticleListDto>(ResultStatus.Success, new ArticleListDto()
                {
                    Articles = articles,
                    ResultStatus = ResultStatus.Success
                });
    }

    return new DataResult<ArticleListDto>(ResultStatus.Error, Messages.ArticleMessages.ArticleNotFound, null);
}
```

DataAccess - Entity Framework Core -> ArticleMap:

```
namespace Blog.DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Mappings
{
    public class ArticleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
            builder.Property(a => a.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(a => a.Title).HasMaxLength(150);
            builder.Property(a => a.Title).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Content).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Content).HasColumnType("NVARCHAR(MAX)");
            builder.Property(a => a.Date).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoAuthor).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoAuthor).HasMaxLength(50);
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoDescription).HasMaxLength(200);
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoDescription).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoTags).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.SeoTags).HasMaxLength(70);
            builder.Property(a => a.ViewsCount).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.CommentCount).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Thumbnail).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Thumbnail).HasMaxLength(250);
            builder.Property(a => a.Slug).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Slug).HasMaxLength(200);
            builder.Property(a => a.CreatedByName).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.ModifiedByName).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.CreatedDate).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.ModifiedDate).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.IsActive).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.IsDeleted).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(a => a.Note).HasMaxLength(500);

            builder.HasOne<Category>(a => a.Category).WithMany(c => c.Articles).HasForeignKey(a => a.CategoryId);
            builder.HasOne<User>(a => a.User).WithMany(u => u.Articles).HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);
            builder.ToTable("Articles");
        }
    }
}
```

`ArticleListDto`:

```
namespace Blog.Entities.Dtos
{
    public class ArticleListDto : DtoGetBase
    {
        public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
namespace Blog.MVC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
                = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.LoadMyServices();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseStatusCodePages();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers - `ArticleController` (for JSON output):

```
namespace Blog.MVC.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ArticleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IArticleService _article;

        public ArticleController(IArticleService article)
        {
            _article = article;
        }

        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var result = await _article.GetAll();
            if (result.ResultStatus == ResultStatus.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result.Data);
            }

            return BadRequest(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public class ArticleListDto : DtoGetBase {
>   public IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
> ```

You're sending your fully populated db entities to the front end

Create a new class that has just the properties you want, call it something else so you can distinguish them (ArticleDto) and send a list of that instead.

<strike>Take a look at AutoMapper - it's a library that can convert back and forth between your Article and your ArticleDto so you don't have to laboriously copy every property value out of the Article and into the ArticleDto</strike> - just noticed you appear to already have AutoMapper configured - probably it's used somewhere in the project; Ctrl-F for `.Map` to find a usage you can (probably) copy